# How to make background-color only cover the size of element?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains text inside of it. I want to add a background-color to the div, but I dont want the background-color to take up the entire row. Just the size of the div.

This is the current state:

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>text is here<div>
```

this is the wanted state:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `width: fit-content` and it will have the width of what is inside of the element.

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> random text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `display` to `inline-block`:

```css
div {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```